# user and person associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am designing data model for an application where I have different types of users like students, employees, parents etc. Let us say each of them is called a Person.
I have separate tables for each of these entities which contain the entity specific information. I have a users table which contains user specific information like login_id, password etc.
I have established the relationship between User and Person with the help of two columns on 
users table:
1. person_id integer
2. person_type integer

Here are the class definitions:

```
class User < ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to :person, :polymorphic =>true, :dependent => :destory
end

class Student < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_one :user, :as => :person
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_one :user, :as => :person
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_one :user, :as => :person
end
```

I would like your valuable comments on this design. Is it ok or does it require any changes?

Comment: The problem with the above design is that if I destroy a Student, the associated User is not getting destroyed automatically. Is there a way by which I can specify that if a Person(student or employee or parent) is destroyed then the corresponding should be automatically destroyed?

Comment: Look at `dependent` option to `has_one`. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Comment: Thank you Denis! Your suggestion worked. When I set the :dependent => :destroy on the Person(student or employee or parent) and invoke destory method on the Person then the corresponding user record is deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to the business logic of your app. From what I have understood so far. I would keep it simple and have one model / table called `User` and have a column `category`, which distinguishs the type of user.

Otherwise, you can also have boolean columns: `student`, `parent`, `employee`. Then you could do something like:

```
If @user.student
  ... do something here
elsif @user.parent
  ... etc etc
```